# How to Set BaudRate in order to communicate with USB CDC Serial

Tags: java, libusb, baud-rate, usb4java

In the above program im trying to write and read data to Atmel Sama5d3Xplained Board using Java(ie USB4JAVA package) Usb Programming.
Someone Please help me to Set BaudRate...so that i can try to communicate with Sama5d3Xplained board in order to read and write some data.
 Thanks in Advance

```
    public class exampleusb 
{
    private static final byte[] d2=new byte[] {0x12,0x43, 0x4E, 0x58,0x4E, 0x00, 0x01, 0x10,0x10,0x17, 0x01, 0x10, 0x17, 0x43,0x4E,0x4E, 0x01, 0x10,0x17, 0x43,0x4E,0x4E};
    private static final short VENDOR_ID = 0x03eb;
    private static final short PRODUCT_ID = 0x6119;
    private static final byte INTERFACE = 1;
    private static final byte interfaceNum = 1;
    private static final byte IN_ENDPOINT = 0x82;
    private static final byte OUT_ENDPOINT = 0x01;
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 5000;
    public static void write(DeviceHandle handle, byte[] data)
    {
        ByteBuffer b1=BufferUtils.allocateByteBuffer(data.length);
        b1.put(data);
        IntBuffer transferred = BufferUtils.allocateIntBuffer();
        int result = LibUsb.bulkTransfer(handle, OUT_ENDPOINT, b1,transferred, TIMEOUT);
        if(result!=LibUsb.SUCCESS)
        {
            throw new LibUsbException("Unable to send data", result);
        }else
        {
            System.out.println(transferred.get() + " bytes sent to device");
        }
    }
    public static ByteBuffer read(DeviceHandle handle, int size)
    {
        ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.allocateByteBuffer(size).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        IntBuffer transferred = BufferUtils.allocateIntBuffer();
        int result = LibUsb.bulkTransfer(handle, IN_ENDPOINT, buffer,transferred, TIMEOUT);
        if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS)
        {
            throw new LibUsbException("Unable to read data", result);
        }
        System.out.println(transferred.get() + " bytes read from device");
        return buffer;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int result=LibUsb.init(null);
        if(result !=LibUsb.SUCCESS)
        {
            throw new LibUsbException("Unable to initialize libusb", result);
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("libusb initialised");
        }
        DeviceHandle handle = LibUsb.openDeviceWithVidPid(null, VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);
        if(handle==null)
        {
            System.out.println("test device not found....");
            System.exit(1);
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("device found");
        }
        result =LibUsb.detachKernelDriver(handle, interfaceNum);
        if(result !=LibUsb.SUCCESS)
        {
            throw new LibUsbException("Unable to claim interface", result);
        }
        write(handle, d2);
        ByteBuffer header = read(handle, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your current error?

Comment: Actually there is no error in the above program....But the thing is Im not able to read the data from the Device...  In order to communicate with the usb devices ...we should set Baud rate Accordinngly.....So i want know about how to set baud rate  in USB devices

Comment: Did you ever find an answer here? Can you use usb4java to do serial modem type communication?